# Access violation reading location 0xba2f1498

Tags: c++, c, winapi, access-violation, readdirectorychangesw

I am coding a programming to watch folder. I use `FileWatch.h` library. This is my `FileWatch.h`

```
#ifndef FILEWATCH_H
#define FILEWATCH_H

class FileChangeObserver 
{
public:
    virtual ~FileChangeObserver() 
    { 

    }
    virtual void OnFileChanged() = 0;
};
// information concerning a directory being watched
class FileWatcher 
{
public:
    // Watching file modifications using a loop
    void Init(LPCTSTR filefullpath);
    bool CheckForChanges(DWORD waittime=0);
    // Watching file modification via a thread
    void StartWatchThread();
    bool IsThreadRunning();
    void SynchronousAbort();
    FileWatcher(FileChangeObserver *observer) : hDir(NULL), curBuffer(0),
        filePath(NULL), hWatchingThread(NULL), observer(observer) 
    {
        ZeroMemory(&this->overl, sizeof(this->overl));
        // create the event used to abort the "watching" thread
        hEvtStopWatching = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    }
    FileWatcher()
    {
    }
    ~FileWatcher() 
    {
        SynchronousAbort();
        delete observer;
        free(filePath);
        CloseHandle(hEvtStopWatching);
    }
public:
    HANDLE          hDir;      // handle of the directory to watch
    FileChangeObserver *observer; // function called when a file change is detected
    TCHAR *         filePath;  // path to the file watched
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION buffer[2][512];
        // a double buffer where the Windows API ReadDirectory will store the list
        // of files that have been modified.
    int curBuffer; // current buffer used (alternate between 0 and 1)
    bool NotifyChange();
public:
    // fields for use by the WathingThread
    OVERLAPPED overl; // object used for asynchronous API calls
    HANDLE hWatchingThread; // handle of the watching thread
    HANDLE hEvtStopWatching; // this event is fired when the watching thread needs to be aborted
};
static DWORD WINAPI WatchingThread(void *param);
#endif
```

This is my `FileWatch.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "FileWatch.h"
#include "assert.h"
#if _MSC_VER > 1600
extern "C" {
WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI
GetOverlappedResult(_In_ HANDLE hFile, _In_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped, _Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesTransferred, _In_ BOOL bWait);
}
#endif
bool FileWatcher::IsThreadRunning()
{
    return hWatchingThread && (WaitForSingleObject(hWatchingThread, 0) == WAIT_TIMEOUT);
}
// Ask for the thread to stop and waith until it ends
void FileWatcher::SynchronousAbort()
{
    SetEvent(hEvtStopWatching);
    if (hWatchingThread) 
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(hWatchingThread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hWatchingThread);
        Sleep(500);
        hWatchingThread = NULL;
    }
    CloseHandle(overl.hEvent);
    overl.hEvent = NULL;
    CloseHandle(hDir);
    hDir = NULL;
}
// Start watching a file for changes
void FileWatcher::StartWatchThread()
{
    // if the thread already exists then stop it
    if (IsThreadRunning())
        SynchronousAbort();
    assert(hDir);
    if (!hDir)
    {
        return;
    }
    // reset the hEvtStopWatching event so that it can be set if
    // some thread requires the watching thread to stop
    ResetEvent(hEvtStopWatching);
    DWORD watchingthreadID;
    hWatchingThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, WatchingThread, this, 0, &watchingthreadID);
}
void FileWatcher::Init(const TCHAR* fileFullPath)
{
    // if the thread already exists then stop it
    if (IsThreadRunning())
        SynchronousAbort();
   // str::ReplacePtr(&filePath, fileFullPath);
    //TCHAR *dirPath = path::GetDir(filePath);
    hDir = CreateFile(
        L"C:\\", // pointer to the directory containing the tex files
        FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,                // access (read-write) mode
        FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_DELETE|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  // share mode
        NULL, // security descriptor
        OPEN_EXISTING, // how to create
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS  | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED , // file attributes
        NULL); // file with attributes to copy
   // free(dirPath);
    ZeroMemory(&overl, sizeof(overl));
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    overl.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
    // watch the directory
    ReadDirectoryChangesW(
         hDir, /* handle to directory */
         &buffer[curBuffer], /* read results buffer */
         sizeof(buffer[curBuffer]), /* length of buffer */
         FALSE, /* monitoring option */
         //FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION|
         FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, /* filter conditions */
         NULL, /* bytes returned */
         &overl, /* overlapped buffer */
         NULL); /* completion routine */
}
// Thread responsible of watching the directory containg the file to be watched for modifications
DWORD WINAPI WatchingThread(void *param)
{
    //qDebug()<<"in WatchingThread";
    FileWatcher *fw = (FileWatcher *)param;
    HANDLE hp[2] = { fw->hEvtStopWatching, fw->overl.hEvent };
    for (;;)
    {
        DWORD dwObj = WaitForMultipleObjects((sizeof(hp)/(sizeof(hp[0])))
                                             , hp, FALSE, INFINITE);
        if (dwObj == WAIT_OBJECT_0) // the user asked to quit the program
        {
            //qDebug()<<"in WatchingThread the user asked to quit the program";
            //exit(-1);
            break;
        }
        if (dwObj != WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
        {
            // BUG!
            //assert(0);
           // qDebug()<<"dwObj "<<dwObj<<" last error "<<GetLastError();
            break;
        }
        //qDebug()<<"WatchingThread fw->NotifyChange() ";
        //if (fw->wakeup)
        fw->NotifyChange();
    }
    return 0;
} 
// Call ReadDirectoryChangesW to check if the file has changed since the last call.
bool FileWatcher::CheckForChanges(DWORD waittime)
{
    if (!overl.hEvent)
    {
        return false;
    }
    DWORD dwObj = WaitForSingleObject(overl.hEvent, waittime);
    if (dwObj != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return NotifyChange();
}
// Call the ReadDirectory API and determine if the file being watched has been modified since the last call.
// Returns true if it is the case.
bool FileWatcher::NotifyChange()
{
    //qDebug()<<"in NotifyChange";
    DWORD dwNumberbytes;
    GetOverlappedResult(hDir, &overl, &dwNumberbytes, FALSE);
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *pFileNotify = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *)buffer[curBuffer];
    // Switch the 2 buffers
    curBuffer = (curBuffer + 1) % (sizeof(buffer)/(sizeof(buffer[0])));
    SecureZeroMemory(buffer[curBuffer], sizeof(buffer[curBuffer]));
    // start a new asynchronous call to ReadDirectory in the alternate buffer
    ReadDirectoryChangesW(
         hDir, /* handle to directory */
         &buffer[curBuffer], /* read results buffer */
         sizeof(buffer[curBuffer]), /* length of buffer */
         TRUE, /* monitoring option */
         FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | 
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | 
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION |
            FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
         //FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE, /* filter conditions */
         NULL, /* bytes returned */
        &overl, /* overlapped buffer */
         NULL); /* completion routine */
    // Note: the ReadDirectoryChangesW API fills the buffer with WCHAR strings.
    for (;;) 
    {
        if (pFileNotify->Action == FILE_ACTION_ADDED)
        {
            //qDebug()<<"in NotifyChange if ";
                char szAction[42];
                char szFilename[MAX_PATH] ;
                memset(szFilename,'\0',sizeof( szFilename));
                strcpy(szAction,"added");
                wcstombs( szFilename, pFileNotify->FileName, MAX_PATH);
                if(observer)
                    observer->OnFileChanged();
                return true;
                //OnFileChanged(szFilename,szAction);
               // qDebug()<<"in NotifyChange after OnFileChanged ";
        }
        // step to the next entry if there is one
        if (!pFileNotify->NextEntryOffset)
        {
            return false;
        }
        pFileNotify = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION *)((PBYTE)pFileNotify + pFileNotify->NextEntryOffset);
    }
    pFileNotify=NULL;
    return true;
}
```

In main program, I have:

```
case IDM_ABOUT:
            //DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            {
                FileWatcher *cWatcher = new FileWatcher();
            cWatcher->Init(L"AB");
            cWatcher->NotifyChange();
            break;
            }
```

I have a error messeage that: Access violation reading location 0xba2f1498.
What's solution?

Comment: Nobody is going to untangle that mess. You should supply the trace from debugger. The problem boils down to accessing memory that you are not supposed to access, but it's hard to tell where exactly unless you post debugger trace. So expand your question to get further help.

Comment: I see a  `delete observer` and `free(filePath)` but no code that allocates memory for either, this is besides the fact that you are mixing c style allocation and C++ style allocation together.

Comment: @Haroogan I want watch directory change, can i use this code? any change in folder: delete folder, new folder, rename ... I don't know how to catch them.

Answer (score 3):

You have a default constructor that leaves all your variables uninitialized.

```
FileWatcher()
{
}
```

Which you use here.

```
            FileWatcher *cWatcher = new FileWatcher();
        cWatcher->Init(L"AB");
```

`Init` also leaves several variables uninitialized, such as `curBuffer` in this line.

```
     &buffer[curBuffer], /* read results buffer */
```

That is likely why you are getting `Access violation reading location 0xba2f1498`

A good practice would be to make sure that your object is always completely valid before the constructor finishes.

Comment: @user2284783 You should modify your constructor to initialize **all** member variables that would be invalid if uninitialized.  Which typically means *all of them*.

Comment: @user2284783 For example, it looks like your code will break if `curBuffer` is not `0` or `1`.  So take steps to make sure it's one of those.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. However I don't know how to call function to watch folder change in main. I find it in: [here](https://github.com/kzmkv/SumatraPDF/blob/master/src/SumatraPDF.cpp). I want to after click Help/About we can watch any change in C: drives

Comment: @user2284783 Since that's not the question you asked, I recommend posting that as a new question.  Good luck!  :)

Comment: Thank. Here is new thread: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028469/how-to-catch-folder-monitoring-in-win32-api) :D

Answer (score 1):

In your destructor you have:

```
delete observer;
free(filePath);
```

but you do not check to make sure either one is allocated beforehand which is clearly a problem, especially since your default constructor does not initialize any of these variables. This is beyond the fact that you are mixing C style allocation with C++ style allocation.

Comment: I don't know how to call function to watch folder change in main. I find it in: [link](https://github.com/kzmkv/SumatraPDF/tree/master/src). I want to after click Help/About we can watch any change in C: drives