# How to catch folder monitoring in WIN32 API?

Tags: winapi, directory

I want to catch any change in a directory: For example: add new folder, rename folder, delete folder... It's a WIN32 project not WIN32 Console Application. Thanks,

Comment: Would a C or C++ answer be acceptable?

Comment: C or C++ is OK. Please help me, I don't know more about WIN32 API

Answer (score 1):

There is a Win32 API - FindFirstChangeNotification which is used to monitor the changes in a directory. There is also a code example on MSDN. See the link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: A small bit of example code would make this a much better answer.  The link may someday become dead.